# ngx-daterangepicker-material add calendar icon in the right

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using ngx-daterangepicker-material for date range picker. Its working fine, but  there is requirement to add icon along with textbox. After clicking on that icon, calendar should open. I am struggling to find out the solution.

Is there any default attribute to show icon to users to open the calendar?

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with the same issue, here is the solution that worked for me:

HTML:

```
<input
        #dateRangePicker
        id="calendar-input"
        class="date-range-picker"
        type="text"
        ngxDaterangepickerMd
        [(ngModel)]="dateRangeSelected"
        [showCustomRangeLabel]="true"
        [showWeekNumbers]="false"
        [ranges]="dateRangeRanges"
        [linkedCalendars]="true"
        [showClearButton]="true"
        [locale]="{format: 'MMM DD, YYYY'}"
        [showDropdowns]="true"
        [showRangeLabelOnInput]="false"
        [minDate]="dateRangeMinDate"
        [maxDate]="dateRangeMaxDate"
        (change)="onDateRangeChanged()"
        placeholder="Select please... "/>
<label for="calendar-input" class="date-range-picker-icon fa fa-calendar"></label>
```

css:

```
 .date-range-picker-icon {
  margin-left: -25px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add class="ngx-daterangepicker-action" on elemnt with handler of (click)="open()"

and also add this in component

```
import { DaterangepickerDirective } from 'ngx-daterangepicker-material';
@ViewChild(DaterangepickerDirective) picker: DaterangepickerDirective;
open() {
    this.picker.open();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

ts file

```
 ...
    @ViewChild(DaterangepickerDirective, { static: false }) pickerDirective: DaterangepickerDirective;
  ...
  ...
  openDatepicker() {
    this.pickerDirective.open();
  }
```

html file!

```
<button class="btn btn-primary ngx-daterangepicker-action" (click)="openDatepicker()">
      Open
    </button>
```